# Turning hex string into readable chars

Tags: encryption, encoding

I have this blob of hex data which can be found on 
https://www.reddit.com/r/codes/comments/421xek/can_somebody_help_me_decode_this_blob/

and I am looking to turn it into 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vhlbgmwn37ro7h0/example.csv?dl=0

I have done a lot of work and have taken a lot of advice from the online community, and I really do appreciate it.

I would LOVE more feedback on how I could handle this.

This field is in the db like this...
dropbox.com/s/vhlbgmwn37ro7h0/example.csv?dl=0

I am also trying to learn the process of what you advise so I can handle this on my own.

Comment: What is my question missing to get down voted so much? lol

Comment: This has nothing to do with information security.

Comment: it's not encrypted? I can take it down, do you know another category it xould go in?

Comment: What you are asking to do is to reverse engineer an encrypted string. That's off-topic, as it has nothing to do with security.

Comment: but I have the key! :) I just need help using it to access this secure info. lserni has been doing an AWESOME job walking me through the process of actually reading encrypted data :)

Comment: I am learning info security! :)

Comment: If you have the key and you just need to reverse engineer it, try [Reverse Engineering SE.](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11930/turning-hex-string-into-readable-chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is obviously hex encoded, except for that "0x" prefix which is commonly used for encoding hex.

So the first step is to convert it to binary form.

Once done this, we find a block of binary data, not ASCII.

```
00000000  ed d5 7b 4c 53 57 1c 07  f0 8b 22 c8 43 79 2b 08  |..{LSW....".Cy+.|
00000010  c2 a5 88 9a 8d 76 b4 34  08 22 70 a0 80 22 14 44  |.....v.4."p..".D|
00000020  d4 e0 a6 40 1f b7 52 ad  85 15 6a 04 dd 82 4b 44  |...@..R...j...KD|
00000030  40 33 67 04 04 c7 d0 e9  62 8c 6c 1a 81 3d 54 dc  |@3g.....b.l..=T.|
00000040  2a be 48 74 1a a7 a0 6e  f1 3d 42 b6 11 dd 7c 64  |*.Ht...n.=B...|d|
```

So the next stage is understand what it is.

Since `file data` under Linux does not recognize it as any known format, the first easy test is to try compressing it.

The data is 1407 bytes uncompressed, and 1434 bytes gzip compressed. This funny result is the telltale sign of either encryption, compression, or both.

The next test is to try and guess where the data comes from.

It is from a database, the uppercase hex reminds me of MySQL, so I ask myself "who could have put it in there?" and I think it likely it was a web application using probably PHP. So chances are that it is the result of

```
'0x' . bin2hex(gzcompress(...something...));
```

and so the next attempt is to use `gzuncompress()` from PHP. Another possibility is that someone used the `COMPRESS` function of MySQL, so `UNCOMPRESS` is another possible avenue.

Unfortunately, both attempts seem to fail:

```
mysql> SELECT UNCOMPRESS(UNHEX('ED...'));
```

and

```
<?php var_dump(gzuncompress(hex2bin('ED...'))); ?>
```

return either garbage or NULL.

But there's another SQL server that's an even closer match - Microsoft SQL Server. Which has, lo and behold, a "compressed blob" function. Hex blobs actually start with `0x` just as our mystery data do.

So this could well be some flavour of *deflate* compression ran by SQL Server.

All that remains is getting my hands on a SQL Server to test the hypothesis.

...but this hypothesis fails too, since `UNCOMPRESS(0xED...)` returns exactly the same string as `CONVERT(varchar, 0xED...)`; which is to say, UNCOMPRESS can't uncompress it and returns it unchanged.

**UPDATE**: the processing below relies on the assumption that the text may be encrypted by MS SQL Server, and I relied on the assumption that the encryption is completely opaque (i.e., assertions such as "text is indistinguishable from random" do apply). *This is not the case*. MS SQL Server encrypted data [has a recognizable format, three consecutive zeroes at offsets 17-18-19](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2009/03/30/sql-server-encryptbykey-cryptographic-message-description/). The mystery data show no such telltale.

At this point I have to entertain the hypothesis that the string isn't simply *compressed*, it is actually *encrypted*. Unfortunately, **a good encryption will turn out text undistinguishable from random**, "random looking" means "with maximum entropy", and "compression" has the effect of increasing the entropy density of a text. In other words,

- well-encrypted text (with any algorithm),
- efficiently compressed text
- random text

...**will all look exactly the same**, and there's no easy way of "recognizing" the compression or encryption in the way you could tell that `{"key":"value"}` is JSON, or `II*....` is likely a TIFF stream.

If the text is encrypted, it is likely that it was encrypted using one of the [standard MS SQL functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181860.aspx), which means there's no easy way of recovering the original data unless you happen to know or acquire the key.

## Update - we have a Python script

The program you supplied in the comment can't work as is, because you're using two hex strings and PyCrypto requires binary strings. If you import the binascii module, it ought to work:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import binascii
import gzip, zlib

iv      = binascii.unhexlify('631a5c0147c15d2e3053264131a211dd')
pp      = binascii.unhexlify('6dd247cb95d269b7d7393e67d6fee570')

msg     = binascii.unhexlify('00EDD57B4C(...omitted...)FE06')

obj = AES.new(pp, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

txt = obj.decrypt(msg)

print txt
```

Here, pp is the passphrase and iv is the initial vector. **It does not work** because, first of all, the hex string must be a multiple of 16 bytes, i.e. 32 hex character. It is not; two hex chars appear to be missing. I tried both adding 00 at the end and at the beginning.

Then, the example you supplied has the same pp and iv values, which is strange. You mentioned two different hex strings before, so I tried both of them, in either order; still no joy.

The resulting data was neither plaintext, nor could it be decompressed with either zlib or gzip.

I believe that you'll have to gather some more information about the problem. For instance: where did that Python script come from? It attempts an AES decryption, which seems a good avenue of inquiry.

Comment: Great!!! So the data is coming from an application that reads sensors.  The application stores the sensor data in its own format.  The table looks something like this... 

www.dropbox.com/s/vhlbgmwn37ro7h0/example.csv?dl=0

Comment: I do not think they went the mysql route... it's a proprietary system that compresses it.  We see it on an azure, but we see what they want us to see.  It might be a .net compression? But my friend who is a .net guy could ID it

Btw, thanks for showing me your process!!! I wish I could vote 2 ups for you!

Comment: I can test it in azure! What code should I run?! :)

Comment: If it's compressed with deflate, offzip should be able to find it: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/are-there-any-tools-or-scripts-for-identifying-compression-algorithms-in-executa

Comment: i downloaded it, I am using windows, will it still work? Btw, I had no idea there was a reverse engineering se!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I had already checked known signatures and features of the data. Your hex sequence shows none of those, so signsrch and offzip can't help you.

Comment: @iserni i do have a specific key... but it's 32 characters long, my python program requires a 16 character key.... Could you use a 32 char key?

Comment: it coud be either
631a5c0147c15d2e3053264131a211dd
or
6dd247cb95d269b7d7393e67d6fee570

Comment: OK, that looks like some kind of decryption key, but what's this about a "python program"?

Comment: from Crypto.Cipher import AES
obj = AES.new('631a5c0147c15d2e3053264131a211dd ', AES.MODE_CBC, '631a5c0147c15d2e3053264131a211dd ')

I have no idea what I was doing, but it gave an error that it was the wrong length...
ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long

Comment: the example code I found was from another stck overflow aid, not from my actual problem....

The two codes I actually posted were the two possible keys based on the db

Comment: I am moving this over to reverse engineering.  

Iserni, thanks for this lesson!! This was an awesome walk through!! I will post the link of the new board if I can :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm adding a detail that I forgot to check -- not really useful, except that it would have saved me some time, and it may interest the guys at RevEng.

Comment: Thanks so much, and also, to zip and unzip, did you just write the code to a file with a .zip extension?

Comment: No, I used `zlib.uncompress(data)`. This requires that data is in zlib format, which it might not be.

Comment: I get this error in python when running uncompress...

AttributeError: module 'zlib' has no attribute 'uncompress'

Did ya do anything special?

Comment: Yes, I told you the wrong function. It's "decompress". If it's not zlib data, it will say something to the effect that the header check fails.

Comment: gotchya!!! Thanks man!!! You really taught me a bunch!! :)

Comment: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11930/turning-hex-string-into-readable-chars

not sure if this will even get answered there, but now I know what kinds of things to try :)